# Types of PII for queries into AWS macie

Tags: amazon-web-services, pii, amazon-macie

I tried to make a query for classifying my documents using macie. But i don't know how i can find documents with driver licenses or National Identifications number...

In the examples that it use aws, appear pii_type: "mail" for email or pii_types: "cc_number" for credit cards numbers, but i don't find examples for Birth dates, Ip adresses, Drivers license IDs (USA), National identification numbers (USA).

How/what i can make to search or create a basic alert for these documents?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

pii_types:"national_id"